# C# Async/Await call not working

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to call an async method from a synchronous method and it keeps bombing on the call to `GetUsTraceApiHealth()` but with no errors. What is the problem?

**Calling Method:**

```
public ActionResult TestSSN()
{
    try
    {
        var apiResponse = GetUsTraceApiHealth().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        string responseBody = apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return Json(responseBody, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {                    
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}
```

**Method Being Called:**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetUsTraceApiHealth()
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            string uri = $"https://trace.{ConfigHelper.SterlingDomain}health?deep";

            HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            return apiResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Bombing", "but with no errors"? So then what **is** happening?

Comment: Most likely a deadlock.  Why not make `TestSSN()` async as well?  Then just await the call instead of using `.Result`.

Comment: Make `TestSSN` async and have it return a `Task<ActionResult>`. And use the `await` keyword instead of accessing `.Response`. And don't take an exception, grab the exception's message and then throw a new exception. You'll lose valuable information that way. Just remove that try/catch altogether.

Comment: Side note: Your `catch` blocks are throwing away useful exception information and replacing it with less information.  You should really just get rid of those entirely.

Comment: By the way, you should never read `Task.Result` unless you know what you're doing. If you have code that ensures you're in a setting where the task has already completed, then yes, but otherwise, no. Most likely you have a deadlock situation on your hands. Additionally, your catch block should just be removed, let the original exception propagate up the call stack instead. You're throwing away stack trace, exception type, any additional properties, etc.

Comment: Returning the `HttpResponseMessage` instead of the content is a very bad idea. Just call `httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);`

Comment: Have a read over [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: David, why are the catch blocks "throwing away useful info". I always thought using them is a best practice.

Comment: No, having random catch blocks is horrible practice. The original place where an exception is generated contains a complete stack trace. When you catch it and only store the message, you lose the original stack trace and any custom properties that the original exception had. You're messing the whole process up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the async mantra of "async all the way down".  Basically, you should *almost never* call `.Result` on a task.  In the majority of cases, your calling method should also be async.  Then you can simply await the result of the operation:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestSSN()
{
    //...
    var apiResponse = await GetUsTraceApiHealth();
    string responseBody = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //...
}
```

It should be up to the application host at the top level (in this case ASP.NET and the web server) to handle the synchronization context.  You shouldn't try to mask an asynchronous operation as a synchronous one.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution (and even more importantly the explanation). It worked like a charm!

Comment: David, why are the catch blocks "throwing away useful info". I always thought using them is a best practice.

Comment: @DeanFriedland: For starters, you’re not using them *for* anything.  Putting code in that does nothing useful just because you feel like you’re supposed to is never best practice.  In this particular case, you’re stripping out all of the original exception and replacing it with a new one.  Only the message is retained.  The original exception type, stack trace, any inner exceptions, any other properties of the original exception... lost.  Just remove these try/catch structures entirely, they do only harm and nothing good.

Comment: Oh wow. So is the try/catch useful in any circumstances? Is there a better way to do error handling? I am almost 2 years into my career as a developer and feel like this is super important to know now before I pick up bad habits. I really appreciate the feedback.

Comment: A try/catch structure is certainly useful for error handling.  But in your code above you’re not actually handling the error in any way.  If you have some way of handling the error, do that.  But don’t catch an exception if you’re not going to handle it.

Answer (score 3):

Simplified version of your code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestSSN()
{
    var apiResponse = await GetUsTraceApiHealthAsync();
    return Json(apiResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public async Task<string> GetUsTraceApiHealthAsync()
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        string uri = $"https://trace.{ConfigHelper.SterlingDomain}health?deep";

        return apiResponse = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
    }
}
```

There's no reason to return the `HttpResponseMessage` to read its content as `string`, just use `GetStringAsync`.
Also, never `catch` an exception just to rethrow it. If you need to do that, use:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //log or whatever
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Camilo. I am going to try this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mix the `async` and `sync` operations together. Proper way to perform it is decorating your methods as `async` and simply using `await`;

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestSSN()
{
    try
    {
        var apiResponse = await GetUsTraceApiHealth().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        string responseBody = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return Json(responseBody, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {                    
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}
```

If you don't able to apply `async` in the all paths, you could use `ConfigureAwait` to prevent deadlock.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetUsTraceApiHealth()
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            string uri = $"https://trace.{ConfigHelper.SterlingDomain}health?deep";

            HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return apiResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can leave a kindly comment, I will be glad to improve my answers.

Comment: Sure. I appreciate the response and the help you provided!

Comment: @DeanFriedland, thanks. But I told it to downvoter :).